# Django : Get Annotated values

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class B(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    a_ref = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='sd')
    b_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    b_value = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
```

Now I want to apply filters to A and in the queryset add the value of a_ref when the b_name="first"

```
filter_dict = {key:value}

fallback_filter = Q()
searched_data = A.objects.filter(fallback_filter)
searched_data = annotate(b_searched_value=FilteredRelation('sd', condition=Q(sd__b_name="first")))

for data in searched_data:
    print(data)
```

Now in this data I do not get any reference of `b_searched_value`. I want to directly get the value of `b_value` in data itself and not make another DB call using the 'a_ref'.

Comment: Your code is incomplete which makes your question a little hard to parse. Are you looking for a bug-fix answer, or a pointer to the docs?  If you meant to write `searched_data = searched_data.annotate...`, then likely what you are looking for is a pointer to the docs on [Queryset `values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

Comment: @RishiG Correct I meant `searched_data = searched_data.annotate` but this does not mean that I need a pointer to the docs. the issue remains the same. the annotated value is not available in the returned data.

Comment: @RishiG Does the annotated values not appear in the final data till we use values?

Comment: You should have access to the annotation in the loop as `data.b_searched_value`.  I pointed to that section of the docs because you said you want to "directly get the value", which makes it sound like maybe you were expecting `data` to be a dict of values or something rather than an annotated object of class `A`.